# IOS/Objective-C: Fastest way to check for Internet connection - 2017

Tags: ios, reachability, internet-connection

My code for checking for an Internet connection, I discovered yesterday on an airplane, is excruciatingly slow.  I am using the technique in many older [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx) of checking an NSUURL, however, it literally took fifteen seconds or more to return FALSE when on an airplane with no connectivity making the app essentially unusable.

Is there a dependable asynchronous method that would do this? People recommend Tony Million's reachability class in older answers but it seems very complicated and Apple is apparently rejecting some apps [using it](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability).  Would appreciate it if someone could suggest the fastest, reliable way to check Internet connection in 2017.  Thank you.

```
- (BOOL)connected
    {
        NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
        if (data) {
            NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Respect for chartering a private jet for your testing environment. Have an upvote for that.

Comment: This is Apple's own sample code. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html

Comment: how to improve Xcode IDE;)

Comment: Apple's code seems incredibly complicated for checking connectivity.  They suggest you build a separate project in Xcode to see how it works.  Can this really be the best way?

Comment: I link to the question that is said to be a duplicate in the second line of my question. The reason I reasked the question in 2017 is that the accepted answer in the linked to question is from 2009.  Marian provides a convincing updated answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reachability is the correct way... even in 2017.

All the various Reachability classes are based on Apple's sample code.

It might seem complicated because it uses C APIs. But usage is simple:

```
- (BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

    if ([reach isReachable]) {
        NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

If you will be using Apple's Reachability class instead of Tony Million's, replace `[reach isReachable]` with `[reach currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable`.

Don't worry that Apple might reject an app using it. If that happens to you, just rename the class from Reachability to MyReachability.

Comment: Talking about Wi-Fi connections, this method can only tell if you are connected to a router. It doesn't tell, if that router is actually connected to the Internet.